# Scala awkward contains behaviour

Tags: scala, generics

I was writing a simple application using Scala and I noticed a pretty strange behaviour. I was able to call the contains method of a String class and pass any object to it. Here's a simple code to illustrate it. I used a worksheet and I don't think there is any need to write a main method since it's irrelevant.

```
class Man
val m = new Man
"hello".contains(m)
```

I was quite surprised that Scala compiler didn't complain and returned false. So I've decided to look into the contains a bit more thoroughly.

First, the String class itself doesn't have the contains method. It's located in the StringOps class, to which, as far as I know, String can be implicitly converted.  The method looks like this in Scala 2.11 docs:

> def contains[A1 >: Char](elem: A1): Boolean
>
> Tests whether this sequence contains a given value as an element.

Therefore, as I understand the type bounds, the elem must be of a  supertype of a Char. The question is, how can this be, that the Man class is a supertype of a Char? Is there any implicit conversion? I've noticed that 2.10 Scala docs contain another definition of contains:

> def contains(elem: Any): Boolean Tests whether this string contains a
>   given value as an element.

This method looks pretty logical for me, since Man class is clearly Any as well. However, the most recent documentation I've found contains the definition I provided earlier.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your claim with Scala 2.11.6 with which  "hello".contains(m) evaluates to False in the REPL.

Comment: Well, I've never stated it would give a 'true'. The issue was not with it.

Comment: Thank you, I think it pretty much explains the behaviour. For some reason, I wasn't able to find any answers, albeit I did try.

Answer (score 4):

`StringOps` extends `StringLike` which extends `IndexedSeqOptimized[Char, String]` which is covariant in the element type. This means you can do this:

```
val s: IndexedSeqOptimized[Any, String] = "hello"
```

This means you can provide an instance of `Any` to contains, which `m` is.